# How to delete image from its image path

Tags: android, image, delete-file

Problem in deleting image from its path. really confused in deleting it from the application as well from the gallery
I'm facing problem in deleting image from image View hot to delete it from the activity as well as the external media of the file location.

Trying it since 3 days and found no solution yet. I need to apply the delete button code in this java file

```
    public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity {

    private Utils utils;
    private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter, image;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    Button btnClose, btnShare, btnDelete;
    private static Context mContext;

     ContentResolver contentResolver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

        adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this,
                utils.getFilePaths());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // displaying selected image first
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btnShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnshare0);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndelete);

        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                File file = new File(adapter._imagePaths.get(viewPager
                        .getCurrentItem()));
                Intent mShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                mShareIntent.setType("image/*");
                mShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mShareIntent, "Shareith:"));
            }
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                            deleteTmpFile(viewPager.getCurrentItem());

                            break;
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                builder.setMessage("Delete this Photo?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();


            }
        });
    }

    public void deleteTmpFile(int pos) {
        //String Foldername = mContext.getResources()
            //  .getString(R.string.app_name);
        /*
         * String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
         * + "/" + Foldername + "/" +data.get(pos) ;
         */
        File f = new File(adapter._imagePaths.get(viewPager
                .getCurrentItem()));
        //File f = new File(filepath);
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
            deleteFileFromMediaStore(mContext.getContentResolver(), f);
            // final Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            // mContext.getContentResolver().delete(uri,
            // MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " =?",
            // new String[] { filepath });

            notifyAll();
        }
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Delete Successfully..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

        public static void deleteFileFromMediaStore(
                final ContentResolver contentResolver, final File file) {
            String canonicalPath;
            try {
                canonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                canonicalPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            }
            final Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
            final int result = contentResolver.delete(uri,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?",
                    new String[] { canonicalPath });
            if (result == 0) {
                final String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                if (!absolutePath.equals(canonicalPath)) {
                    contentResolver.delete(uri, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA
                            + "=?", new String[] { absolutePath });
                }
            }

        }


}
```

Comment: Well what does not work? And what does work?

Comment: when i do click on the delete button then the app crashes

Comment: In such a case you can find the cause in the LogCat. Please post a relevant part of it here. You have to find which line of code causes this. And then tell us.

Comment: The problem is solved by me but now when i`m pressing the back button then the image is coming again but it is deleted but again showing it back.. why?

Comment: Tell what the problem was and post the modified code.

Comment: i need to refresh in this

Answer (score 0):

I think your MediaStore is not updated.Have you tried this function after deletion

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(fileDeleted)));
```

For 4.4 and lower

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: well it is not even deleting anything  when i click on delete button then it crashes

Comment: The problem is solved by me but now when i`m pressing the back button then the image is coming again but it is deleted but again showing it back.. why?

Comment: you need to refresh your view pager with new list of data

Comment: i need to refresh in this

Answer (score 0):

```
  package com.example.fakenewspapermaker;

import info.androidhive.imageslider.helper.Utils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;



import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity {

    private Utils utils;
    private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter, image;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    Button btnClose, btnShare, btnDelete;
    private static Context mContext;

     ContentResolver contentResolver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

        adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this,
                utils.getFilePaths());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // displaying selected image first
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btnShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnshare0);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndelete);

        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                File file = new File(adapter._imagePaths.get(viewPager
                        .getCurrentItem()));
                Intent mShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                mShareIntent.setType("image/*");
                mShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mShareIntent, "Share with:"));
            }
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {


                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                            File file = new File(adapter._imagePaths.get(viewPager
                                    .getCurrentItem()));
                            if (file.exists())
                            {
                                file.delete();

                            }
                            finish();


                            break;


                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FullScreenViewActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Delete this Photo?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();


            }
        });
    }

    public void deleteTmpFile(int pos) {
        //String Foldername = mContext.getResources()
            //  .getString(R.string.app_name);
        /*
         * String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
         * + "/" + Foldername + "/" +data.get(pos) ;
         */
        File f = new File(adapter._imagePaths.get(viewPager
                .getCurrentItem()));
        //File f = new File(filepath);
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
            deleteFileFromMediaStore(mContext.getContentResolver(), f);
            // final Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            // mContext.getContentResolver().delete(uri,
            // MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " =?",
            // new String[] { filepath });

            notifyAll();
        }
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Delete Successfully..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

        public static void deleteFileFromMediaStore(
                final ContentResolver contentResolver, final File file) {
            String canonicalPath;
            try {
                canonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                canonicalPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            }
            final Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
            final int result = contentResolver.delete(uri,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?",
                    new String[] { canonicalPath });
            if (result == 0) {
                final String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                if (!absolutePath.equals(canonicalPath)) {
                    contentResolver.delete(uri, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA
                            + "=?", new String[] { absolutePath });
                }
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
            finish();
              Intent newIntent = new Intent(FullScreenViewActivity.this,
                MySavedNews.class);
              newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              startActivity(newIntent);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see questions answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486529/delete-file-from-internal-storage)

and for your case after delete by checking a boolean variable if true then reload/refresh your list.